# Image color reduction

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

Just for the fun of it, I was looking of ways to make true-color GIFs.
I've started to write the code, and it clicked me: this won't work for that, but it does make a nice color-reduction method.

Basically, it works like this:

- Gets all the colors of the image, and counts how many times it shows in the image
- Tries to replace similar colors, withing a given distance, with the most used color
- Redraws the image, replacing the previous color with a new one

With the maximum compression, you can reduce the number of colors up to 60%.
Sadly, the images are all heavy-weight PNG files, and from level 5 onwards, they start to look funky.
Still, it is an interesting concept, in my opinion.

```
;(function(window, undefined){
    var canvas = window.document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // all values: Math.pow(2, <level>);
    var MAX_COMPRESSION = 7;
    var DEFAULT_COMPRESSION = 4;

    var methods = {
        colors: function(data){
            var colors = {};

            for(var color = j = i = 0, l = (data.length / 4); i < l; ++i)
            {
                j = i * 4;

                // representing data[j] first caused weird color issues
                color = data[j + 3]
                    ? data[j + 2] + (data[j + 1] << 8) + (data[j] << 16)
                    : -1; // -1 <-- no color, just transparent

                colors[color] = color in colors
                    ? colors[color] + 1
                    : 1;
            }

            return colors;
        },
        compress: function(data, level){
            // compressing with transparent pixels returns weird results
            // skip them already
            var new_data = data['-1']
                ? {'-1': data['-1']}
                : {};
            delete data['-1'];

            level = Math.pow(2, level) || DEFAULT_COMPRESSION;

            var colors = Object.keys(data);
            var removed = {};

            for(var i = 0, l = colors.length; i < l; ++i)
            {
                var color = colors[i];
                new_data[color] = data[color];

                var next = colors[i + 1];
                var distance = methods.distance(color, next);
                while(
                    next
                    && distance.r < level
                    && distance.g < level
                    && distance.b < level
                    && (distance.r + distance.g + distance.b) < level
                )
                {
                    // keeps the most used color
                    if(new_data[color] >= data[next])
                    {
                        new_data[color] += data[next];
                        removed[next] = color;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        new_data[next] = new_data[color] + data[next];
                        removed[color] = next;
                        delete new_data[color];
                        color = next;
                    }

                    next = colors[++i + 1];
                    distance = methods.distance(color, next);
                }
            }

            /* avoids situations like:
                {
                    123456: 54321,
                    54321: 6543
                }
                normalizes to:
                {
                    123456: 6543,
                    54321: 6543
                }
            */
            for(var k in removed)
            {
                if(removed[k] in removed)
                {
                    removed[k] = removed[removed[k]];
                }
            }

            return {
                colors: new_data,
                removed: removed,
                stats: {
                    before: colors.length,
                    savings: Object.keys(removed).length
                }
            };
        },
        distance: function(a, b){
            a = +a;
            b = +b;
            return {
                r: Math.abs(b - a),
                g: Math.abs((b >> 8) - (a >> 8)),
                b: Math.abs((b >> 16) - (a >> 16))
            };
        },
        draw: function(imgdata, colors, width, height){
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;

            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            // early return in case we didn't save a single color
            if(!colors.stats.savings)
            {
                context.putImageData(imgdata, 0, 0);
                return canvas;
            }

            var data = imgdata.data;
            var target = context.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);

            for(var color = j = i = 0, l = (data.length / 4); i < l; ++i)
            {
                j = i * 4;

                // if it is a completely transparent pixel,
                // keep it transparent (aka: opacity at 0)
                if(!data[j + 3])
                {
                    target.data[j] = 0;
                    target.data[j + 1] = 0;
                    target.data[j + 2] = 0;
                    target.data[j + 3] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    color = data[j + 2] + (data[j + 1] << 8) + (data[j] << 16);

                    if(color in colors.removed)
                    {
                        // integer conversion was required here
                        color = +colors.removed[color];
                        target.data[j] = (color >> 16) & 255;
                        target.data[j + 1] = (color >> 8) & 255;
                        target.data[j + 2] = color & 255;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        target.data[j] = data[j];
                        target.data[j + 1] = data[j + 1];
                        target.data[j + 2] = data[j + 2];
                    }

                    // transparency is important
                    target.data[j + 3] = data[j + 3];
                }
            }

            context.putImageData(target, 0, 0);

            return canvas;
        }
    };

    var fn = function(image, compression_level){
        // setting the width and height erases the content in the canvas
        // there's no need to clean it up
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;

        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        try
        {
            var imgdata = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            // tainted canvas, no need to write to the console
            // all major browsers write a warning already
            return null;
        }

        var colors = methods.colors(imgdata.data);

        // tries to convert into an usable value
        compression_level = ((+compression_level) | 0) || 0;
        if(compression_level)
        {
            colors = methods.compress(colors, compression_level > MAX_COMPRESSION ? MAX_COMPRESSION : compression_level);
        }
        else
        {
            // build compression result structure
            colors = {
                colors: colors,
                removed: {},
                stats: {
                    before: Object.keys(colors).length,
                    savings: 0
                }
            };
        }

        return {
            canvas: methods.draw(imgdata, colors, canvas.width, canvas.height),
            stats: colors.stats
        };
    };

    window.reduceColors = fn;
})(Function('return this')());
```

You can try it below:

```js
;(function(window, undefined){
 var canvas = window.document.createElement('canvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
 // all values: Math.pow(2, <level>);
 var MAX_COMPRESSION = 6;
 var DEFAULT_COMPRESSION = 4;
 
 var methods = {
  colors: function(data){
   var colors = {};
   
   for(var color = j = i = 0, l = (data.length / 4); i < l; ++i)
   {
    j = i * 4;
    
    // representing data[j] first caused weird color issues
    color = data[j + 3]
     ? data[j + 2] + (data[j + 1] << 8) + (data[j] << 16)
     : -1; // -1 <-- no color, just transparent
    
    colors[color] = color in colors
     ? colors[color] + 1
     : 1;
   }
   
   return colors;
  },
  compress: function(data, level){
   // compressing with transparent pixels returns weird results
   // skip them already
   var new_data = data['-1']
    ? {'-1': data['-1']}
    : {};
   delete data['-1'];
   
   level = Math.pow(2, level) || DEFAULT_COMPRESSION;
   
   var colors = Object.keys(data);
   var removed = {};
   
   for(var i = 0, l = colors.length; i < l; ++i)
   {
    var color = colors[i];
    new_data[color] = data[color];
    
    var next = colors[i + 1];
    var distance = methods.distance(color, next);
    while(
     next
     && distance.r < level
     && distance.g < level
     && distance.b < level
     && (distance.r + distance.g + distance.b) < level
    )
    {
     // keeps the most used color
     if(new_data[color] >= data[next])
     {
      new_data[color] += data[next];
      removed[next] = color;
     }
     else
     {
      new_data[next] = new_data[color] + data[next];
      removed[color] = next;
      delete new_data[color];
      color = next;
     }
     
     next = colors[++i + 1];
     distance = methods.distance(color, next);
    }
   }
   
   /* avoids situations like:
    {
     123456: 54321,
     54321: 6543
    }
    normalizes to:
    {
     123456: 6543,
     54321: 6543
    }
   */
   for(var k in removed)
   {
    if(removed[k] in removed)
    {
     removed[k] = removed[removed[k]];
    }
   }
   
   return {
    colors: new_data,
    removed: removed,
    stats: {
     before: colors.length,
     savings: Object.keys(removed).length
    }
   };
  },
  distance: function(a, b){
   a = +a;
   b = +b;
   return {
    r: Math.abs(b - a),
    g: Math.abs((b >> 8) - (a >> 8)),
    b: Math.abs((b >> 16) - (a >> 16))
   };
  },
  draw: function(imgdata, colors, width, height){
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   canvas.width = width;
   canvas.height = height;
   
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   
   // early return in case we didn't save a single color
   if(!colors.stats.savings)
   {
    context.putImageData(imgdata, 0, 0);
    return canvas;
   }
   
   var data = imgdata.data;
   var target = context.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
   
   for(var color = j = i = 0, l = (data.length / 4); i < l; ++i)
   {
    j = i * 4;
    
    // if it is a completely transparent pixel,
    // keep it transparent (aka: opacity at 0)
    if(!data[j + 3])
    {
     target.data[j] = 0;
     target.data[j + 1] = 0;
     target.data[j + 2] = 0;
     target.data[j + 3] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
     color = data[j + 2] + (data[j + 1] << 8) + (data[j] << 16);
     
     if(color in colors.removed)
     {
      // integer conversion was required here
      color = +colors.removed[color];
      target.data[j] = (color >> 16) & 255;
      target.data[j + 1] = (color >> 8) & 255;
      target.data[j + 2] = color & 255;
     }
     else
     {
      target.data[j] = data[j];
      target.data[j + 1] = data[j + 1];
      target.data[j + 2] = data[j + 2];
     }
     
     // transparency is important
     target.data[j + 3] = data[j + 3];
    }
   }
   
   context.putImageData(target, 0, 0);
   
   return canvas;
  }
 };
 
 var fn = function(image, compression_level){
  // setting the width and height erases the content in the canvas
  // there's no need to clean it up
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  
  try
  {
   var imgdata = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
  catch(e)
  {
   // tainted canvas, no need to write to the console
   // all major browsers write a warning already
   return null;
  }
  
  var colors = methods.colors(imgdata.data);
  
  // tries to convert into an usable value
  compression_level = ((+compression_level) | 0) || 0;
  if(compression_level)
  {
   colors = methods.compress(colors, compression_level > MAX_COMPRESSION ? MAX_COMPRESSION : compression_level);
  }
  else
  {
   // build compression result structure
   colors = {
    colors: colors,
    removed: {},
    stats: {
     before: Object.keys(colors).length,
     savings: 0
    }
   };
  }
  
  return {
   canvas: methods.draw(imgdata, colors, canvas.width, canvas.height),
   stats: colors.stats
  };
 };
 
 window.reduceColors = fn;
})(Function('return this')());

var file = document.getElementById('file');
var image = document.getElementById('image');
var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');

file.onchange = function(){
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.addEventListener('load', function () {
  image.src = reader.result;
 }, false);

 if(file.files[0])
 {
  reader.readAsDataURL(file.files[0]);
 }
};

image.onload = function(){
 gallery.innerHTML = '';
 for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
 {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var result = reduceColors(image, i);
  div.innerHTML = 'Compression: ' + i + ' (colors before: ' + result.stats.before + ', removed: ' + result.stats.savings + ')<br>';
  div.appendChild(result.canvas);
  gallery.appendChild(div);
 }
};
```

```css
/* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361986/css-gradient-checkerboard-pattern */
img, canvas {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #CCC 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #CCC 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #CCC 75%), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #CCC 75%);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 10px, 10px -10px, -10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*">
<br>
<img id="image">
<div id="gallery"></div>
```

Or try on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nwnse9hx/15/

---

This code was written purely for fun, but that's not an excuse to write it poorly.
Still, I feel that there's something to improve on it.

Besides of any performance issue that there might be, and some readability crimes, what else can I improve in this code?

Comment: Timeline profiling shows a lot of time is spent in `colors` function. In a [similar](https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string/issues/47) heavy-calc + lookup case switching all objects to Map() and/or Set() produced a 2x speedup.

Comment: How would that work, if the `colors` has to be executed for every image?

Comment: It is an interesting idea. And I said that because you said "you'll be probably better off re-using a persistent variable which can be emptied with `.clear()` method".

Comment: I've found 2 things that actually make the code faster: Instead of using the `{}` literal to create objects, using `{}` makes it a few ms faster. Also, `colors[color] = (colors[color] || 0) + 1;` seems faster than `colors[color] = color in colors ? colors[color] + 1 : 1;`.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Here's a [version with Map/Set](https://jsfiddle.net/wOxxOm/k8xfacvz/3/) and (a few other arguably meaningless micro-optimizations) that runs 1.25 - 2+ times faster depending on the image contents. For further improvements the entire algorithm should be changed. Edit: the link is updated.

Comment: @wOxxOm That looks like an amazing code. There's things I am not really getting and don't really like (for example, `for (var [k, v] of removed.entries())` which uses ES6 syntax), but it seems like a really nice code. Can you make it into an answer?

Comment: Answering is kinda bothersome. BTW why ES6 is an issue?

Comment: You can remove `distance.r < level && distance.g < level && distance.b < level` since you already compare their sum < level and the summands can only be positive. Also, you don't replace each color with *the* most frequent one within a distance, because you traverse the colors only in forward direction in the order you encountered them when building the `colors` map (?) and update your frequencies while traversing. It's quite confusing, perhaps you could state more clearly according to which rules you compress?

Comment: @wOxxOm It isn't. I just don't find it any clear. But that's me, nothing else.

Comment: @le_m What I described is what it is supposed to do. If it isn't doing that, then it is a bug. The idea is: I have a red pixel. I want to find all the other colors that are very similar to that pixel, and replace that for the most used color.